# Need docker authorization token for k8s deployment but not in .docker/config.json

Tags: docker

Struggling with this one. Can't find the docs. I need the authorization token to log into k8s and currently the contents of my .docker/config.json just has

```
{
   "auths": {
       "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
   },
   "HttpHeaders": {
       "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.5 (linux)"
   },
   "credsStore": "secretservice"
}
```

I don't know how to change things to get my authorization token which I need for the k8s login.

Comment: What you mean by k8s login. Did you mean login to `kubernetes dashboard` ?

Comment: No, the k8s login to pull docker images.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pull docker images from your registry into kubernetes cluster, you need to:

- Specify `kubernetes secret`. k8s support special type of secret that allows to pull images from registry and refer this secret in pod yaml.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <name> --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

For more info check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

**NOTE:** If kubernetes is running on AWS and docker registry is AWS [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) then assign [appropriate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html#AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly) IAM role to k8s ec2 nodes, k8s will then automatically pull the images.

Hope this helps, let me know.